# onHttpError in klein.php executes every time

Tags: php, exception, router, klein-mvc

I'm using [klein.php](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php/) router, which is really powerful, But Now I want to handle exceptions, 
so from the documentations I'm using this function

```
$klein->onHttpError(function ($code, $router,$matched,$method_matched,$http_exception) {
switch ($code) {
    case 404:
         $router->response()->body(
            '404 Page'
        );
        break;
    case 405:
        $router->response()->body(
            'You can\'t do that!'
        );
        break;
    default:
        $router->response()->body(
            'Oh no, a bad error happened that caused a '. $code
        );
 }
});
```

But even if there is no exception, this function is rendering and printing `404 page` in the end of every page.
Am I doing something wrong? I tried checking `$matched` but no luck.

And I want to use `$service->render()` in error handling, How can I do that? Because service is not accessible in particular `onHttpError` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting, I find out that it is occurring due to `skipRemaining()` function. Then I started to exploring the issues again. Issue [#285](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php/issues/285) provided a solution.

But still I didn't find anyway to render a page in `onHttpError()` function using `$service` object call.

Edit:

To access `$service` object in `onHttpError()`, We have to declare it again. So the code will be

```
$klein->onHttpError(function ($code, $router) {
    $service = $router->service();
    $service->render('your-page-url.php');
});
```